# Failed step "verifyConditions" of plugin "@semantic-release/gitlab"

Tags: gitlab-ci, yarnpkg, semantic-release

I have a problem.

We created gitlab token in our CI/CD

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RkYqK.png)
but I have an error when I push **npx semantic-release**

```
      code: 'ENOGLTOKEN',
      details: 'A [GitLab personal access token](https://github.com/semantic-release/gitlab/blob/master/README.md#gitlab-authentication) must be created and set in the `GL_TOKEN` or `GITLAB_TOKEN` environment variable on your CI environment.\n' +
        '\n' +
        'Please make sure to create a [GitLab personal access token](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/profile/personal_access_tokens.html) and to set it in the `GL_TOKEN` or `GITLAB_TOKEN` environment variable on your CI environment. The token must allow to push to the repository https://gitlab.com/ntl-development/19liters.git.',
      semanticRelease: true,
      pluginName: '@semantic-release/gitlab'
```

My .releaserc.json file is...
`{   "release": {     "verifyConditions": [       "@semantic-release/gitlab"     ],     "publish": [       "@semantic-release/gitlab"     ]   },   "branches": ["test"],   "plugins": [     ["@semantic-release/commit-analyzer", {       "preset": "conventionalcommits"     }],     ["@semantic-release/release-notes-generator", {       "preset": "angular",       "parserOpts": {         "noteKeywords": ["feat"]       },       "writerOpts": {         "commitsSort": ["subject", "scope"]       }     }],     ["@semantic-release/changelog", {       "SEMREL_CHANGELOG_FILE": "CHANGELOG.md",       "SEMREL_CHANGELOG_ENABLED": true,       "SEMREL_TAG_FORMAT": "$${version}"     }],     ["@semantic-release/git", {       "assets": ["package.json"],       "message": "chore(release): ${nextRelease.version} [skip ci]\n\n${nextRelease.notes}"     }],     ["@semantic-release/exec" ],     ["@semantic-release/npm"],     ["@semantic-release/gitlab", {       "gitlabUrl": "https://gitlab.com",       "verifyConditions": [         "@semantic-release/gitlab"       ],       "tagFormat": "v${version}",       "assets": [         { "path": "dist/asset.min.css", "label": "CSS distribution" },         { "path": "dist/asset.min.js", "label": "JS distribution", "target": "generic_package" },         { "path": "dist/asset.min.js", "label": "v${nextRelease.version}.js" },         { "url": "README.md" }       ]     }]   ] }`

and my .package.json is

`"release": {     "branches": [       "test"     ],     "tagFormat": "v${version}",     "verifyConditions": [       "@semantic-release/changelog",       "@semantic-release/gitlab",       "@semantic-release/npm"     ],     "prepare": [       "@semantic-release/changelog",       "@semantic-release/npm"     ],     "publish": [       "@semantic-release/gitlab"     ],     "fail": [       "@semantic-release/gitlab"     ],     "GITLAB_URL": "https://gitlab.com/ntl-development/19liters"`

PLZ help

I try add gitlab token with my hands in file, he sees token, but didn't work
$ npx semantic-release --debug

Answer (score 0):

package.json

```
  },
  "release": {
    "branches": [
      "test"
    ],
    "tagFormat": "v${version}",
    "verifyConditions": [
      "@semantic-release/changelog",
      "@semantic-release/gitlab",
      "@semantic-release/npm"
    ],
    "prepare": [
      "@semantic-release/changelog",
      "@semantic-release/npm"
    ],
    "publish": [
      "@semantic-release/gitlab"
    ],
    "fail": [
      "@semantic-release/gitlab"
    ],
    "GITLAB_URL": "https://gitlab.com/ntl-development/19liters"
  },
  "jest": {
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "json",
      "ts"
    ],
    "rootDir": "src",
    "testRegex": ".*\\.spec\\.ts$",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "**/*.(t|j)s"
    ],
    "coverageDirectory": "../coverage",
    "testEnvironment": "node"
  }
}
```

release.json

```
{
  "release": {
    "verifyConditions": [
      "@semantic-release/gitlab"
    ],
    "publish": [
      "@semantic-release/gitlab"
    ]
  },
  "branches": ["test"],
  "plugins": [
    ["@semantic-release/commit-analyzer", {
      "preset": "conventionalcommits"
    }],
    ["@semantic-release/release-notes-generator", {
      "preset": "angular",
      "parserOpts": {
        "noteKeywords": ["feat"]
      },
      "writerOpts": {
        "commitsSort": ["subject", "scope"]
      }
    }],
    ["@semantic-release/changelog", {
      "SEMREL_CHANGELOG_FILE": "CHANGELOG.md",
      "SEMREL_CHANGELOG_ENABLED": true,
      "SEMREL_TAG_FORMAT": "$${version}"
    }],
    ["@semantic-release/git", {
      "assets": ["package.json"],
      "message": "chore(release): ${nextRelease.version} [skip ci]\n\n${nextRelease.notes}"
    }],
    ["@semantic-release/exec" ],
    ["@semantic-release/npm"],
    ["@semantic-release/gitlab", {
      "gitlabUrl": "https://gitlab.com",
      "verifyConditions": [
        "@semantic-release/gitlab"
      ],
      "tagFormat": "v${version}",
      "assets": [
        { "path": "dist/asset.min.css", "label": "CSS distribution" },
        { "path": "dist/asset.min.js", "label": "JS distribution", "target": "generic_package" },
        { "path": "dist/asset.min.js", "label": "v${nextRelease.version}.js" },
        { "url": "README.md" }
      ]
    }]
  ]
}
```